# Java - what is a method with a apparently no signature

Tags: java, methods, constructor

in other words, can someone explain to me the purpose of this:

```
Consumer(Producer p) {
    producer = p;
}
```

in the context of:

```
class Consumer extends Thread {
    Producer producer;

    Consumer(Producer p) {
        producer = p;
    }
}
```

as I understand, it appears to be a method with no signature, or a constructor since it shares the class name, yet it doesn't show up in my IDE as such. Can someone explain what it is and what it does?

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, the ide is netbeans. It changes the icon for the class member, but isnt very clear about telling me that it is still a constructor, just one with different to usual access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Consumer(Producer p) { ... }` is a constructor for the `Consumer` class.

You typically see constructors as `public`, e.g.:

```
public Consumer(Producer p) { ... }
```

However, when the `public` (or any access modifier, e.g. `protected`, or `private`) is not specified (for any method or member, including constructors), the constructor is only available to the package the class is declared in.

Have a look at Oracle's tutorial on [access control](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

Answer (score 4):

You are looking at a constructor of class Consumer.  The only problem I can see is it is not given a access level (public, private, etc...), so it looks like it will default to package-protected, meaning only classes within the same package can see it.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say that not having that is a "problem" - it may rightly be intentional. :)

Comment: @Rob - very true.  I meant problem in the sense that it might be what is causing his IDE not to pick up on it.

Comment: Strange that the IDE wouldn't pick it up. Perhaps it's a bug in the IDE.

Comment: @Rob - that's what I was thinking.  Seems like a pretty straightforward (and common) thing, so perhaps it is an IDE bug.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's a constructor. It may *look* like a "method with no signature" syntactically (more specifically, a constructor cannot have a return type, but may have access modifiers and of course parameters), but it's really quite different from a method in several ways.

The purpose of a constructor is to create instances (objects) of the class. With some relatively exotic exceptions (cloning and deserialization), every Java object is created by calling a constructor. Every class has at least one constructor, but if none is declared an the superclass has a constructor with no parameters, the compiler implicitly adds a parameterless constructor that does nothing except call the superclass constuctor. Similarly, the first thing any constructor does is call a superclass constructor. Again, this can be implicit if there is a parameterless constructor in the superclass.

As for why constructors don't show up in your ide: it's probably a configuration option. To say more, we'd have to know which IDE that is.

Comment: Ahh right, im aware of constructors, id just never seen one without an access modifier. It threw me a bit when the ide (Netbeans) gave it a different icon, then declined to identify what was different about it (or that it was in fact still a constructor). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, that is a package protected constructor, i.e. it can only be called from methods of the class itself or other classes in the same package. I'm not sure what benefit that has over the more commonly used `protected` or `private` constructors, which prevent a class from being directly instantiated and are commonly used to implement the [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern.

Comment: This is misleading. If package-private, it can be called by non-static or static methods in the declaring package. Using a package-private constructor would also not be ideal for creating Singletons, since any other class in the package could instantiate it.

Comment: Ok, accept your first comment (which was an oversight on my part because I was thinking of singletons) but I never said anything about package-private constructors, just plain private (and protected). I was adding information that the OP requested ("the purpose of this") which your original answer was lacking. Down-voting my answer is extremely harsh.

Comment: Your first-sentence reference to "package protected" is the "package-private" reference I was referring to. I interpreted the "This" in your last sentence as referring to your first sentence rather than your second, since the antecedent for the "This" is ambiguous. I didn't intend any aggression by the downvote, and I don't believe it is "extremely harsh."

Comment: In the absence of disambiguation, "This" clearly refers to the last thing mentioned, protected or private constructors in this case. A downvote is for an answer that "is not useful". At the time of writing, my answer was arguably a lot more useful than your original single line "That's a package-protected constructor" answer.

Comment: Per the FAQ: "If you see misinformation, vote it down." If you edit your answer to be clearer and correct, I will rescind my vote.